# What do you do with a show: 'shut down' or 'close'?

Tags: word-request

There's the word 'cancel' but it doesn't fit my needs as only the company that airs a show can cancel it. In my case, it's, let's suppose,

> There were numerous attempts by Christian activists to [the word] the controversial show as they deemed it immoral.

Comment: Usually "shut down" fits the circumstances. The show could be cancelled or closed for a number of reasons, but this implies it was forced on them.

Comment: @WeatherVane By "this" you mean 'shut down', right?

Comment: Yes, sorry if poorly phrased.

Comment: @WeatherVane By the way, is my notion about the usage of the word 'cancel' correct?

Comment: "Cancel" can mean that the show's organisers decided not to open the show (perhaps due to poor advance ticket sales) or closed it after it opened (perhaps due to illness, or poor attendance).

Comment: @WeatherVane Is it yes? (note the word 'only' in that sentence)

Comment: Isn't that what I said? The *show's organisers* closed it. I put "can" because I went on to give different reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"shut down", "cancel" and "closed" all have similar meanings, but rather different connotations in this precise example.

"closed" implies that the scheduled run has come to an end, normally, nothing unusual.

"cancel" tends to imply that a show did not even start.

"shut down" has clearly negative connotations here, and is often used like: "shut down by the authorities" i.e. stopped due to a perceived violation of a rule, or indeed of public morals.